# Connected component labeling in matrix

Tags: matrix, components

I'm trying to do the following
Given the following matrix (where 1's are empty cells and 0's are obstacles):
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
I want it to become like this:
0 0 1 1
2 0 0 0
2 0 2 2
2 2 0 0

What I need to do is to label all connected components (free spaces).
What I already tried to do is to write a function called isConnected() which takes indexes of two cells and checks if there is a connected path between them. And by repeating this function n^2 times on every empty cell on the matrix I can label all connected spaces. But as this algorithm has a bad time complexity (n^2*n^2*O(isConnected())) I prefer to use something else.
I hope these pictures will explain better what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could look into flood algorithms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill